# Unit testing .Net CF apps on Windows Mobile 6.5.3 in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: unit-testing, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Did anyone get that to work? I mean, unit testing .Net CF apps on Windows Mobile 6.5.3 in Visual Studio 2008.

It works great for a WM 6 Pro target, but not for a WM 6.5.3 target.

I get this error:

```
The test adapter ('Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter, Version=9.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') required to execute this
test could not be loaded. Check that the test adapter is installed properly.
Not enough storage is available to process this command.
```

Yes, I can *read* the error text, but I don't understand the failed run.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference: The only way I could make this problem go away turned out to be a complete reinstall of the WM 6 SDK and 6.5 DTK. Shortly after that I upgraded to Windows 7 and reinstalled VS 2008 with the 6.5.3 DTK and the shebang, and testing still works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that CF 3.5 isn't installed on the target device (it's an option, not a requirement for the OEM).  You can manually install it, or create a CF 3.5 app (like the app you're testing) and deploy it once to have Studio deploy the CF runtimes.

Comment: @ctacke: Thanks, Chris, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I've already deployed and run the main app numerous times, so the 3.5 stuff is already there. It seems like "the test adapter" isn't compatible with the new 6.5.3...

Comment: Update: After upgrading to Windows 7 and reinstalling VS 2008 with the 6.5.3 DTK, testing works as expected.